# Reuse views and controller logic in MVC3

Tags: renderaction, asp.net-mvc

in my MVC3 based application I often need to reuse the same functionality in different views.

Example: One view to search for users. Another view to show the search results and enable the user to select one or more of the returned records. At the end those records have to be passed to the original view/controller.

How can I use (if at all) RenderAction and a, let's say, UserAccountSelectionController to build a reusable set of controller(s) and views? How would my reusable controller "know" where to pass the selected user models to? Is there a different approach to create reusable components the MVC3 way?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Try creating a partial to handle both actions.